# How can I pass UTM parameters from URL to an iframe?

Tags: iframe, parameters, marketo

- i have a link google adword :

  http://example.com?utm_campaign=Testcam&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=Blog&utm_content=blogers&utm_term=Test
- When visitor click the link above to navigate to mysite. And then he submit a Marketo form (non Marketo form for landing page on my site).
  I follow this article to create Mkto form on my site: http://community.marketo.com/MarketoResource?id=kA650000000GsPJCA0 to make sure when it submit it will get values from url parameters.
- My  problem on here is : Normally, this form just submit to the server to handle register. Beside that, when this form submmited, i also need it submit to Marketo for tracking. That a reason, Marketo form will be submit via iframe.

When i submit marketo form, it will be target to this iframe.

So, i need pass the url parameter into iframe to make sure when submit form, hidden fields will automatic get values from url parameters. But on this iframe, as you can see, it haven't src. I had try to add this to iframe:

```
$("#mktoformhidden").src = window.location.href;
```

but it doesn't work well.

What's the iframe src should be on here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this! Just replace "URL HERE" with your iframe url and of course update the sizing that you need in BOTH loactions.

```js
<noscript>
 <iframe src="YOUR URL HERE" width="100%" height="500" type="text/html" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border: 0"></iframe>
</noscript>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var iframeurl = 'YOUR URL HERE';
 var params = window.location.search;
 var thisScript = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1];
 var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

 iframe.setAttribute('src', iframeurl + params);
 iframe.setAttribute('width', '100%');
 iframe.setAttribute('height', 500);
 iframe.setAttribute('type', 'text/html');
 iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', 0);
 iframe.setAttribute('allowTransparency', 'true');
 iframe.style.border = '0';

 thisScript.parentElement.replaceChild(iframe, thisScript);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that an iframe is not the best solution here.  The iframe can create all sorts of cross site scripting and permission based concerns.

Why not just use the new forms functionality in Marketo so you can drop the form either on a landing page or embed on your site (they come with an embed source code).

Also, the munchkin tracking code automatically grabs "query" parameters so you can use those in smart lists or reporting.

Comment: Do you mean that, i will create 2 new forms in one landing page on Marketo? And i will able to embed source code of two forms in my site, when the first submitted, the 2nd form will be automatic submit!

Comment: Not exactly.  The new Marketo Forms 2.0 give you an "embed source" code so that you don't have to do any of that iFrame stuff.  You just drop it on the site.  The munchkin tracking code picks up those utm parameters natively.  You can get those by the query_string selection in the visit_page selection.  You can also add the form post to your form handler (*.php page or whatever) via ajax.  Kind of a double form post.  Or you could have the Marketo form trigger a webhook that calls your form handler.

Answer (score 1):

Like [sahutchi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2940064/sahutchi) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22279967/255317), embedding the actual Marketo *form* into your site could be the way to go. I opted for the iframe approach to get Marketo to automatically fill in fields based on `mkt_tok`. This might be possible using Marketo forms, but I wasn't able to figure it out a month or two ago.

Here's a decent overview of ways that you can integrate Marketo forms with your site: http://www.elixiter.com/marketo-landing-page-and-form-hosting-options/

If you *insist* on doing it the iframe way, here's my setup to pass query string params down to the embedded iframe:

This is in `http://yourdomain.com/my-marketo-page`:

```
<div class="lazy-iframe" data-src="//pages.yourdomain.com/MyMarketoPage.html" style="width: 960px; height: 1000px;">
</div>
```

And in some shared library (but you can have it on the same page, and simplify it a bit):

```
<script>
$(function() {
  var $lazyIframe = $('.lazy-iframe');
  if ($lazyIframe.length) {
    var src = $lazyIframe.attr('data-src');
    if (src) {
      var $iframe = $('<iframe src="' + src + location.search + '"></iframe>');
      $iframe.attr({
        scrolling: 'no',
        frameborder: 0
      });
      $lazyIframe.replaceWith($iframe);
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Given that `pages.yourdomain.com` is your `CNAME` to your Marketo domain.

In my email, I just link to `http://yourdomain.com/my-marketo-page`, and Marketo will automatically add the `mkt_tok` for that email recipient to the end of that URL (becoming `http://yourdomain.com/my-marketo-page?mkt_tok=BLAHBLAHBLAH`). Then the iframe is constructed with the `data-src` URL and all of the parameters attached, and with no scrolling nor frameborder (up to you).